# Magento 1.9 show custom option in order grid

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I  have created a simple product with custom option and have placed the order https://prnt.sc/t36x0i

I wanted to show the selected custom option in the order grid  here [https://prnt.sc/t36xm0] can anyone help me with this to show the custom option in order grid 
I have copied the code from app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php to 
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

please find the code below

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Adminhtml sales orders grid
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        // $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        // $this->setCollection($collection);
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
            ->join(
                'sales/order_item',
                '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
                array(
                    'skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",")'),
                    'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
                    )
                );
                $collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');
                $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('skus', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Skus'),
            'width'     => '100px',
            'index'     => 'skus',
            'type'        => 'text',

        ));
    $this->addColumn('names', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Name'),
            'width'     => '100px',
            'index'     => 'names',
            'type'        => 'text'));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id',
                            'data-column' => 'action',
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
            ));
        }

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're best using something like BL Custom Grid - although its unmaintained it works on all versions of Magento 1 (I've tested 1.6.x-1.9.x).

It adds a fully customised grid to every section (Products, Orders, Customers) and allows you to add custom attributes to the grid, create multiple views and much more - I genuinely can't recommend it enough!

https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids/tree/1.0.0-wip